# Swift Compiler - Custom Flagsを追加する方法がわからず

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode7

Xcode7.3です。

- [Xcode6,Swiftで APIのURLを分ける - Qiita](http://qiita.com/ryusukefuda/items/63194d1165cdaea18ec9)
- [ios - #ifdef replacement in swift language - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-swift-language)

を参考にカスタムフラグをセットしようとしています。

### 1. pod install前の状態

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`pod install`をする前はこのようになにもありませんでした。

### 2. pod install後の状態

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### pod install後の状態詳細

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`pod install`後はこのようにカスタムフラグが自動で付与されていました。

### 3.BANANAフラグを追加

`pod install`後の状態でBANANAフラグを追加しようとして、下記のようにすると
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 4.BANANAフラグ追加後の状態

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このように何故か　"-D" "COCOAPODS"が２つ表示されます。
正しい追加の仕方を教えて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

２つの目のリンクを見るとBANANAではなく-DBANANAを入れているように見えますのでそれで試して下さい。

２つ重複して出てもCOCOAPODSのdefineは有効のようで問題はないのでそこは無視しよいと思います。